# Is it easier to read the mind of a Sith than a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, jedi

Reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111024/110291) answer it seems like it's easier to read someone's mind with the Force when they are experiencing strong feelings. Jedi believe in suppressing emotion and resisting strong feelings, while Sith believe in using their emotions and feelings to their advantage and embracing them. Does this mean that it would be easier to read the mind of a Sith than of a Jedi? If so that might explain why Rey was able to read Kylo's mind so easily.